# Mapbox fitBounds, function bounds map but does not render tiles

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, mapbox

Here, my javascript code to render markers in map and after that fitBounds of that map.

Map bounds are get fit according to geojson, but problem is that when there is any marker
on map and I try to fit bound, map tiles images are not get render.

In map it display only markers, no tile images.

```
var latLongCollection = [];
    var map;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    map();
    });


    function map() {
      map = L.mapbox.map('DivId', 'ProjectId');
      GetData();
     }

    function GetData() {
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: someUrl,
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: AjaxSuccess,
           error: function () {
           }
       });
    }

     function AjaxSuccess(data) {
      if (data == null || data.length == 0) {
          return;
      }

      var geoJson = {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": []
      };

      $.each(data, function (index, value) {

          var latitude = parseFloat(value.Latitude),
              longitude = parseFloat(value.Longitude);

          if (latitude && longitude) {
              var dataJson = {
                  type: "Feature",
                  geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [longitude, latitude] },
                  properties: {
                      someProp: value.SomeProperty,
                      }
              };

              geoJson.features.push(vehicleJson);
          }
      });

      var markerLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(geoJson).addTo(map);

      markerLayer.eachLayer(function (marker) {
           var feature = marker.feature;
           var featureProperty = feature.properties;

           if (featureProperty.someProp) {
               marker.setIcon(L.divIcon({
                   html: 'htmlstring',
                   iconSize: [35, 75]
               }));
           }
           else {
               marker.setIcon(L.divIcon({
                   html: 'anotherhtmlstring',
                   iconSize: [35, 75]
               }));
           }

           latLongCollection.push(marker._latlng);
    });

     markerLayer.on('click', function (e) {
         map.panTo(e.layer.getLatLng());
     });

        if (latLongCollection.length > 0) {
           map.fitBounds(latLongCollection);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If anyone is still struggling with this, it appears to be a bug in Leaflet: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2021

It has been fixed in the latest version, but if you can't update you can work around the race condition by setting a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    map.fitBounds(latLongCollection);
}, 0);
```

Comment: later, I try same as u say.

Comment: Upgrading leaflet to  v=0.7.5 (Latest version) is not solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

How did you try debug the problem? What's your network and js console saying?

Try to zoom out, maybe fitBounds zooms your map too much. I had this problem. The solution was using maxSize option in fitBounds, see leaflet docs.

Comment: No,map zoom level is not maximum and no console error is coming. When I see network, mapbox js aborted all request to load tile images. so no tile images get display.